RPI pico write to flash programatically
I am trying to write a program for the pico in rust, that needs to save data between possible shutdowns. It would fit into the flash with the program and the flash is "according to the internet" writable.
I have copied some embassy pico template repo and changed memory.x to contain a section .log that is 1M in size.
MEMORY {
    BOOT2 : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x100
    FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x10000100, LENGTH = 1M - 0x100
    LOG   : ORIGIN = 0x10100000, LENGTH = 1M
    RAM   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 256K
}

EXTERN(BOOT2_FIRMWARE)

SECTIONS {
    /* ### Boot loader */
    .boot2 ORIGIN(BOOT2) : {
        KEEP(*(.boot2));
    } > BOOT2
    /* Data log */
    .log : {
        *(.log);
       . = ALIGN(4);
    } > LOG
} INSERT BEFORE .text;

Then in my code I have
#[link_section = ".log"]
static mut LOG: MaybeUninit<[u8; 1 << 20]> = MaybeUninit::uninit();

fn foo() {
    let log = unsafe { LOG.assume_init_mut() };
}

But I can see from the behavior and debugging that assigning to the array does nothing. The section  is initially zeroed out and stays like that even after assignment.
I have verified this with a simple test function, that checks if the memory is writable.
fn test_writable(log: &mut [u8]) -> bool {
    let prev = log[0];
    let masked = prev ^ 0xb5;
    log[0] = masked;
    if log[0] == masked {
        log[0] = prev;
        true
    } else {
        if log[0] == prev {
            error!("Log is not writable");
        } else {
            error!("Log writing is incorrect. Prev: {}, expected: {}, current: {}", prev, masked, log[0]);
        }
        false
    }
}

Am I using MaybeUninit wrong, is the memory map wrong or something else?

You can't just assign to a variable stored in flash, it doesn't respond the same way RAM does.  It is possible to write to the flash chip attached to the RP2040, but you have to send the right commands to it.  You should probably find an example in the pico-sdk, or if there is none then find out how MicroPython does it (it stores a writable filesystem in the RP2040's flash).

While it's possible for some processors to memory map flash so that you can read from it, writing to flash is a more involved process because it typically is designed such that an entire page is erased at a time. It depends on the microcontroller and the flash, but typically there is a special command you need to invoke to erase the page first before you can write to it. After that, some microcontrollers will let you write to a memory mapped address after you've erased, others might require you to use a special command mechanism as @DavidGrayson notes.

As a side note to whomever is reading this, I'd avoid anything that writes to flash on a frequent basis (i.e. for logging purposes). Flash memory has a limited life span (< 10000 writes), you will wear out the memory.

The RPIPico does memory-map its flash memory to "normal" addresses for reading, so you can simply read from flash addresses. For writing, that flash is not directly addressable - writing directly to flash addresses doesn't achieve anything useful.
Note the below is valid for the C API functions - you'll need to find the proper Rust equivalents in your SDK.
You need to use the API functions
flash_range_erase (offset, size)
flash_range_write (offset, buffer, size)

to first erase a certain block in flash, then write it.
To complicate matters a bit, apparently both functions will only work properly with interrupts disabled. Also, you need to make sure you don't erase/write to a flash area that holds your program.
Flash on the RPi 2040 must be handled in blocks of 4k - That means, you must make sure you're writing to the next block to the next address "behind" your program in flash that can be evenly divided by 4096. Your last program address is conveniently provided by the libraries in the flash_binary_end variable (which is an absolute address, while the two above functions want offsets relatively to the start of the flash memory, which can be found by the constant XIP_BASE).
So, in order to write a block of data at blockof length 4096 to flash memory behind  your program code, you can conceptually do the following:
void *flashAddress = (flash_binary_end + 4096) & 0xfffff000;
int flashOffset = flashAddress - XIP_BASE;
uint32_t ints = save_and_disable_interrupts();
flash_range_erase (flashOffset, 4096);
flash_range_write (flashOffset, block, 4096)
restore_interrupts (ints);


The Standard picow flash is a https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/949/w25q16jv_spi_revg_03222018_plus-1489727.pdf A fairly standard NOR flash. When you erase a 4k sector, it is all set to 0xff.
The wear on flash is mainly the erase, but also the writing of "0" bits.
But the interesting thing to think about is you can write less than 4k in the range write. Only one bits to zero flash bits are actually changed. So if you wanted to record several ssids for example, you could allocate 64 bytes to ssid and password. Then new ssids could be added much later in product use. Also the network start program could try all ssids by starting with the first 64 byte, then if it fails to connect proceed to the next ssid in flash. The program could give up when it encounters a blank (all 0xff) block of 64 bytes. In a 4k page (2^12) using 64 byte blocks (2^6), there are 2^6 = 64 blocks available.
Note you can usually erase some of the flash page by writing 0x00 - even if you already wrote something. Not necessarily applicable for ssid info, but for other data this might be useful. You could scan all your blocks for the last written block for the most recent also (just look for any block with a 0 bit somewhere).
